# Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null - XML & JS

Tags: javascript, html, xml, getelementbyid

I am attempting to display the data from a XML file to my website via JavaScript. I have used this JavaScript code on its own just with a basic HTML document and it works fine, displaying the data and allowing me to click and view other data in from the XML file.

However, when I copied the code to a page of my website, the code won't run and I keep getting the error message "Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null". I find this bizarre as it is the exact same code that I used with a basic HTML page and it worked fine...

I have attached the HTML from my website below. Any advice or a fix**strong text** would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <section id="middle_XML">
    <h1>BOOK LIST</h1>

<div align ='center'>

<p>Click on a CD to display album information.</p>
<p id='showBook'></p>
<table id="demo"></table>
</div>

<script>
var x,xmlhttp,xmlDoc
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "booklist.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");

table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";

for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
table += "<tr onclick='displayBook(" + i + ")'><td>";
table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
table += "</td><td>";
table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
table += "</td></tr>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

function displayBook(i) {
document.getElementById("showBook").innerHTML =
"Artist: " +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Title: " +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Year: " + 
x[i].getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>About: " +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("about")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Price: " + 
x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>



</section>
```

Below is the code that works on a basic HTML page. Why won't it work when copied across on to my webpage?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
border : 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
 }
th,td {
padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div align ='center'>

<p>Click on a CD to display album information.</p>
<p id='showBook'></p>
<table id="demo"></table>
</div>

<script>
var x,xmlhttp,xmlDoc
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "booklist.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");
table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
table += "<tr onclick='displayBook(" + i + ")'><td>";
table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
table += "</td><td>";
table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
table += "</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

function displayBook(i) {
document.getElementById("showBook").innerHTML =
"Artist: " +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Title: " +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Year: " + 
x[i].getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>About: " +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("about")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"<br>Price: " + 
x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That error is telling you your variable is null, check the variable before trying to use it. For instance make sure `xmlDoc` is not null, that `x[i]` is not null etc

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I kind of get what your saying. I just can't understand why the exact same code works on a basic HTML page and not my website.

Comment: Well do you have a `booklist.xml` file in the same directory as your html page? Did you check your that your request is completing successfully, ie check Network tab of the browsers Developer's Tools